# App Engine Backends Configuration (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend, task-queue

I got `timeout` error on my GAE server when it tries to send large files to an EC2 REST server. I found `Backends` Python API would be a good solution to my example but I had some problems on configuring it.

Following some instructions, I have added a simple `backends.yaml` in my project folder. But I still received the following error, which seems like I failed to create a backend instance.

```
  File "\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\background_thread\background_thread.py", line 84, in start_new_background_thread
    raise ERROR_MAP[error.application_error](error.error_detail)
FrontendsNotSupported
```

Below is my code, and my question is:

1. Currently, I got timeout error in `OutputPage.py`, how do I let this script run on a backend instance?

#### update

Following Jimmy Kane's suggestions, I created a new script `przm_batchmodel_backend.py` for the backend instance. After staring my GAE, now it I have two ports (a default and a backend) running my site. Is that correct?

#### app.yaml

```
- url: /backend.html
  script: przm_batchmodel.py
```

#### backends.yaml

```
backends:
- name: mybackend
  class: B1
  instances: 1
  options: dynamic
```

#### OutputPage.py

```
from przm import przm_batchmodel
from google.appengine.api import background_thread

    class OutputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            form = cgi.FieldStorage()
            thefile = form['upfile']

            #this is the old way to initiate calculations
            #html= przm_batchmodel.loop_html(thefile)  

            przm_batchoutput_backend.przmBatchOutputPageBackend(thefile)

            self.response.out.write(html)
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', OutputPage)], debug=True)
```

#### przm_batchmodel.py

```
    def loop_html(thefile):
        #parses uploaded csv and send its info. to the REST server, the returned value is a html page. 
        data= csv.reader(thefile.file.read().splitlines())
        response = urlfetch.fetch(url=REST_server, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers, deadline=60)   
        return response
```

#### przm_batchmodel_backend.py

```
    class BakendHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=przm_batchmodel.loop_html, args=[thefile])
            t.start()
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/backend.html', BakendHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an application 'file'/script for the backend to work. Just like you do with the main.

So something like:

app.yaml

```
- url: /backend.html
  script: przm_batchmodel.py
```

and on przm_batchmodel.py

```
class BakendHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

        html = 'test'
        self.response.out.write(html)
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/backend.html', OutputPage)], debug=True)
```

May I also suggest using the new feature [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) which are easier to setup?

**Edit** due to comment

Possible the setup was not your problem.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#background_threads)

> Code running on a backend can start a background thread, a thread that
>   can "outlive" the request that spawns it. They allow backend instances
>   to perform arbitrary periodic or scheduled tasks or to continue
>   working in the background after a request has returned to the user.

You can only use `backgroundthread` on backends.

So edit again. Move the part of the code that is:

```
 t = background_thread.BackgroundThread(target=przm_batchmodel.loop_html, args=[thefile])
 t.start()
 self.response.out.write(html)
```

To the backend app

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added `class BakendHandler` as you suggested but still got the same `FrontendsNotSupported` error. I am running GAE on a windows environment and use its GUI button to start my app, and is that correct?

Comment: And don't forget. Use the backgroundthread on the backend and not the frontend, as I saw in your updated question @tao.hong

Comment: So you mean frontend scripts could not contain backend contents, right?

Comment: @tao.hong depending on how you define backend content. The main difference is that requests can take longer. There are other differences like the backgroundthread but not many that I can recall. Image backends as an handler or application that can pass the 60s limit and live as long as you are able to pay ;-).

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestions and GAE creates an backend instance for me (at a different locally port), which looks the same as the regular instance. In the backend.yaml, I only provide very brief information, so GAE automatically cloned my regular site?

Comment: @tao.hong hmm strange. Cloning cannot happen. Are you sure you do not provide the same functionality? I mean are you sure that the request is passed to the backend? Can you alter the backend app to do something different? Or maybe I don't understand you well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47453/discussion-between-jimmy-kane-and-tao-hong)